# How to avoid commas between each character of a string when writing on a CSV with writerow and not writerows?

Tags: python

I've the following piece of code:

```
with open('filename.csv',  'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as arquivo:
    escritor = writer(arquivo)
    linha = 'Summary'
    escritor.writerow(linha)
```

The output of this code is a csv file where the first row is presented this way:

[image]

I saw similar issues here on StackOverflow and solution was always to use **writerow** instead of **writerows** which is something that I'm already doing.
Can someone help me to fix this thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `writerow` expects an iterable by default; the characters in your string are being interpreted as the elements of that iterable. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). Note that a CSV with a single column is just a newline-delimited text file.

Comment: Any way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Put each row in a list, like the docs say. Or avoid the CSV module because you're not actually creating a CSV.

Comment: you always have to use list (even if you have only one element) `.writerow( [ linha ] )`. And for `writerows` it will need list of lists `.writerows( [ [linha] ] )`

Comment: Are you sure you need CSV file *at all*?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use list (even if you have only one element)

```
escritor.writerow( [ linha ] )
```

And for `writerows` you will need list of rows (even if you have only one row)

```
escritor.writerows( [ [linha] ] )
```

---

More detailed for `writerow` (without `s`)

```
item = 'Summary'
row = [ item ]   # list with all elements in row (even if you have only one item)
escritor.writerow( row )
```

More detailed for `writerows` (with `s`)

```
item = 'Summary'
row = [ item ]      # list with all elements (even if you have only one item)
all_rows = [ row ]  # list with all rows (even if you have only one row)
escritor.writerows( all_rows )
```